# Append not working in Jquery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I have the following, inside a function in javascript triggered by a validation

```
         $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "pags_din.php",
           data: {idSurvey: $survey},
           success: function(data) {
              $("#dynamic").append(data);
              console.log(data);
              $("#startSurvey").click();
           }
          });
```

somehwere else in the same page I have

```
<a id="startSurvey" href="#dynamic" data-transition="slide"></a>
```

and somewhere else also in the same page I have

```
<div id="dynamic"></div>
```

In console I succesfully read this after triggering the function

```
<div id="header" data-role="header">
    <h1><img src="images/logo.png" /></h1>
</div>
```

But it is not appending in the #dynamic div the code displayed in console

After browsing and asking I can't tell what could be the problem :(

Anyone? please!

Thanks in advance

EDIT: Of course I add a lot more than an image, I load content dynamically created from a query made from a form modified by the user so this is the best way for me to do it ( I think )

Answer (score 0):

Because it is still an object, parse it to string first.
You can use Stringify.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm very new to this
you meant:

$("#dynamic").append(JSON.stringify(data));

Because I get this in console when using JSON.stringify
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: Sorry I thought the returned result was JSON object. If it was just plain text, then your div should display them correctly. If not, you need to transform your result to html elements then (not in an array for instance). Also be careful of " vs '